# statsmodels arma(1,0) does not match AR(1)

Tags: python, statsmodels

Can anyone explain why the ARMA(1,0) model does not match an AR fit with maxlags=1? What are these models doing differently?

```
a = [ 6.12970357,  6.13318109,  6.12992128,  6.1273058 ,  6.12839643,
            6.12424563,  6.11080196,  6.10680013,  6.0860927 ,  6.07901746,
            6.0872292 ,  6.08381584,  6.08107671,  6.08881808,  6.06819407,
            6.06471499,  6.0537349 ,  6.05255967,  6.04334514,  6.03572065]


ar1model = ar_model.AR(a).fit(maxlag=1)
ar1model.params
```

array([-0.09735684,  1.01516508])

```
model10=ARMA(a, (1,0)).fit()
model10.params
```

array([ 6.08423432,  0.97711525])

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that ARMA imposes stationarity through reparameterization, while AR does not.

Also,the ARMA constant is the long term average, while the AR constant is from the dynamic equation `y_t = const + b * y_{t-1}`. In a stationary AR(1) with `|b| < 1`, the long term constant would be `const / (1 - b)`.

The parameterization of the ARMA model is in terms of the residual, i.e. it is a regression model with ARMA errors:

A(L) (y_t - const) = B(L) u_t

or in the ARMA(1,0) case

y_t - const - b (y_{t-1} - const) = u_t
or written for y_t
y_t = b y_{t-1} - (1 - b) const + u_t

see for example http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/ and http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimaconstants/ for the two possible parameterizations.

Additional sources of differences in the results especially in small samples could be different default initialization or different default estimation algorithms, and in ill conditioned problems the starting values could also have an influence on the final outcome.
In general, both AR and ARMA assume that the process is stationary, while the results indicate that the root is around one and might not be stationary. Maybe estimating the differenced series will produce better results.

(I am not as familiar with the AR implementation in statsmodels.)

Comment: I tried the same function calls with transparams=False, and also received different answers. I'm also not sure what you mean - isn't the function for ARMA(1,0) also exactly the same as the function for AR(1)? `y_t = const + b * y_{t-1}`

{transparams : bool, optional

    Whehter or not to transform the parameters to ensure stationarity. If False, no checking for stationarity or invertibility is done.}
[statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit)

Comment: @dimab0 I added more information to my answer. ARMA uses a different model, and you have possibly non-stationarity which would cause problems for the estimation.

Comment: I am no expert here and may very possibly be incorrect, however, I think that AR(1) = ARMA(1,0). I think it is possible that your solution is trying to explain the differences between AR and ARIMA? See the first section of http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~bb/TS_Chapter4_6.pdf

Comment: AR(1) = ARMA(1,0) if they follow the same parameterization and estimate under the same restrictions. In large samples they will essentially estimate the same process if it is stationary. In small samples and a possibly non-stationary process, they might not.

Comment: The reason I came across this was from a large data set of daily nasdaq prices, which follow close to a random walk - hence the B1 ~ 1. The difference is B0 between the two models though, I can't explain. The B0 from the ARMA fit seems unrealistic.